# Testing with Travis CI an AngularJS application that uses SASS

Tags: angularjs, sass, gruntjs, travis-ci

I can't figure out why my TravisCI build keep failing (on node 0.10) while compiling my SASS files.

I keep receiving the same error:

```
Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But I've installed both sass and grunt-contrib-sass, as you can see by my `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js                                                                                                                              

before_install:                                                                                                                                
  - gem install sass                                                                                                                           

node_js:                                                                                                                                       
  - '0.8'                                                                                                                                      
  - '0.10'                                                                                                                                     

before_script:                                                                                                                                 
  - 'npm install -g bower grunt-cli karma'                                                                                                     
  - 'bower install'                                                                                                                            

script: grunt
```

and my (excerpt) of `package.json`

```
"grunt-bower-install": "~1.0.0",                                                                                                          
"grunt-concurrent": "~0.5.0",                                                                                                              
"grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",                                                                                                           
"grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.2",                                                                                                         
"grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",                                                                                                          
"grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",                                                                                                         
"grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
```

Anyone knows what could be going on?

Link to my Travis build: https://travis-ci.org/dmatteo/ng-bootstrap-pure/builds

p.s. of course my locale `grunt` is testing and building flawlessly

Comment: Can you please link to your travis-ci build?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't thought about it. I'll also add it in the post

https://travis-ci.org/dmatteo/ng-bootstrap-pure/builds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the installation of `sass` wasn't enough, and `compass` was needed to.
Moreover, I needed to specify that a GUI was needed, and this is done in the first two lines of `before_install`

So, this is the working `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js

before_install:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - gem install sass
  - gem install compass

node_js:
  - '0.10'
  - '0.11'

before_script:
  - 'npm install -g bower grunt-cli karma'
  - 'bower install'

script: grunt
```